# Como pasar parametros con referencia a un script bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, shell-script

Tengo una duda con un script bash linux, tengo la necesidad de pasar parametros por cabecera y que se recojan en mi script con un nombre de variable en especifico y no un $1 o $@.  Me explico mejor, dado este script:

```
\#!/bin/bash

[[ -d ”${DB_PATH}" ]] || mkdir -p -m 755 ”${DB_PATH}" 

[[ -d ”${LOG_PATH}" ]] || mkdir -p -m 755 ”${LOG_PATH}”
```

**¿Tengo alguna manera que al ejecutarlo y que las variabes `DB_PATH` y `LOG_PATH` ya estén con el valor definido?**

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción que se me viene a la mente es usar `getopt` y otra es procesar los datos de entrada para que posteriormente se puedan utilizar con comodidad.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ $# > 0 ]]  # Itero sobre la cantidad de parametros que se ingresaron.
do
    case "$1" in
        -p1 | --param1 )
            shift  # Una vez que se encuentra el patron "-p1" o "--param1"
                   # Se recorre el indice del array de argumentos.
            declare param1="$1"  # Entonces el siguiente valor de entrada se almacena en la variable "param1"
            shift  # Y se vuelve a recorrer para proceder con este método.
        ;;
        -p2 | --param2 )
            shift
            declare param2="$1"
            shift
        ;;
        * ) 
            # En caso de no coincidir, de igual forma se recorre el indice para
            # continuar con el bucle.
            shift
        ;;
    esac        
done 

# Ahora ya puedes usar los parametros por nombre.

echo "param1: $param1"
echo "param2: $param2"
```

Que al momento de ejecutar sería algo de a forma.

```
./named_params.sh --param1 hola --param2 adios
param1: hola
param2: adios
```

Para `getopts`, puede revisar esta pregunta.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a invocar tu programa varias veces, quizás te convendría establecerlas como variables de entorno:

> export DB_PATH=dbpath
>   export LOG_PATH=logpath
>   miscript

Si es para usarlas una única vez, tienes 2 opciones:

1. Establecerlas al llamar a tu programa:

> DB_PATH=valor1 LOG_PATH=valor2 miscript

2. Usar la orden `env`:

> env DB_PATH=valor1 LOG_PATH=valor2 miscript